# Steps for making a C++/CLI application portable across WIndows and Unix?

Tags: .net, c++, c++-cli, portability, managed

I have a client that has a managed C++ DLL library that needs to be able to run on Unix. There aren't a lot of references to .NET specific code in there except for the files that receive the inputs from an external process/thread. The project is currently compiled on Visual Studio.NET 2010. What are some steps to follow in order to make this happen? Obviously, I will need to create makefiles on the Unix side for example. Another thing I will need to do is to replace classes that are using .NET properties to use getters/setters (is this the best way to go?). Their front end GUI is currently an Excel/Visual Basic application that calls this DLL library to perform calculations on a set of data. However, they are going to rewrite the front-end as well (not sure what technology they are going to use). I'm assuming that another I will need to do is replace CLI types in the code with native types. Am I correct in my assumptions so far? What other bigger things will need to be done? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a C++/CLI or a Managed C++ DLL?

Comment: don't forget, under Unix there are no DLLs. the libraries there a quite different. you should start with thinking about your interface: how the program is going to contact your library?

Comment: @Vlad: Ever hear of `dlopen()`?

Comment: @Nemo: I don't mean the dynamically loading libraries, I mean the semantics. Hint: what if you define a global variable in a DLL?

Comment: I'd used CMake (it just works) instead of trying to maintain separate VS project files and make files.

Answer (score 0):

Managed code is quite different to native code- you will need to completely re-write all parts of the DLL that depend on the .NET Framework, assuming that installing Mono or something like that isn't an option. And then compile it as native C++ for Linux. Some .NET code will transfer over easily, like the use of Collections to the Standard containers, but some of it won't- for example, you'll have to devise the resource ownership strategy from scratch. I would be concerned also about how the *calling* code is going to be altered to run on Unix, if it expects a managed interface.

Comment: Honestly I don't see how these days installing mono would not be an option. It's a dependency of Gnome. Problem here is that Mono does not support C++/CLI assemblies unless they're pure managed code. Mixed-mode assemblies are not supported because they're obviously not portable.